# Using regex to match non-word characters BUT NOT smiley faces

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a Java program which is supposed to remove all non-letter characters from a string, except when they are a smiley face such as =) or =] or :P

It's very easy to match the opposite with `[a-zA-Z ]|=\)|=\]|:P` but I cannot figure out how to negate this expression. Since I am using the String.replaceAll() function it must be in the negated form.

I believe part of the issue may come from the fact that smiles are generally 2 characters long, and I am only matching 1 character at a time?

Interestingly, `replaceAll("(?![Tt])[Oo]","")` removes every occurrence of the letter O, even in the word "to." Does this mean my replaceAll function does not understand regex lookahead? It doesn't throw any errors...

I ended up using

```
replaceAll("(?<![=:;])[\\]\\[\\(\\)\\/]","")
.replaceAll("[=:;](?![\\]\\[\\(\\)o0OpPxX\\/])","")
.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z=:;\\(\\)\\[\\]\\/ ]","")
```

which is extremely messy but works perfectly. `The... quick! (brown) fox jump's over the[] lazy dog. :] =O ;X` becomes `THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG :] =O ;X`

**Edit:** Ignore that fix, see the accepted answer below.

Comment: Interesting! Note that :-) and >:^} are over 2 characters. :)

Comment: Is that a troll? I did include the word "generally"

Comment: TrueWill's statement seems factual and non-troll-like to me.

Comment: Why use regexes over simple pattern matches? Just build a table of smilies, and iterate across the characters in the string. Test at that index against possible smilies. If not, remove it. If yes, skip that many characters. Repeat.

Comment: I did not intend to troll. I did +1 the question, but wanted to note that it is open-ended unless one defines precisely what a "smiley" is. See for instance [Western emoticons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons#Western).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to due this using a negative lookahead.  Basically the match will fail at any position where the regex inside of the `(?!...)` group matches.  You should follow the negative lookahead with a single wildcard (`.`) to consume a character if the lookahead did not match (meaning that the next character is a non-letter character that is not part of a smiley face).

**edit:** Clearly I hadn't tested my original regex very thoroughly, you also need a negative lookbehind following the `.` to make sure that the character you consumed was not the second character in a smiley:

```
(?![a-zA-Z ]|=\)|=\]|:P).(?<!=\)|=\]|:P)
```

Note that you might be able to shorten the regex by using character classes for the eyes and the mouth, for example:

```
[:=][\(\)\[\]]
  ^    ^-----mouth
  |--eyes
```

Comment: 'Testing. =] =) :P don't (fail)!' becomes 'Testing = = :P dont fail'

Comment: I also tried with an extra set of parenthesis (?!([a-zA-Z ]|=\)|=\]|:P)). and it still does not work.

Comment: Interestingly, replaceAll("(?![Tt])[Oo]","") removes every occurrence of the letter O, even in the word "to." Does this mean my replaceAll function does not understand regex lookahead? It doesn't throw any errors

Comment: @Kevin - I just edited my answer and it should now be working properly, sorry about that.  The reason your above regex is replacing every occurrence of O is that the lookahead does not consume any characters, so you regex could be described as "match if the next character is not a T, and is an O".  If you want to match every O that is not preceded by a T, you should use a negative lookbehind: `(?<![Tt])[Oo]` ("match if the previous character is not a T, and the next character is an O").

Comment: That makes sense now, I was thinking of it incorrectly. Thank you for explaining.