# Remove extra punctuation from string while keeping "smileys"?

Tags: java, regex

I am running into some problems using the regular expression. Can you please help me out?
The following in the problem I am trying to solve -

```
Input - :,... :(..:::))How are you today?..:(
Output - :( :) How are you today :(
```

Basically I want to remove the punctuations from the input string like-(.,:; etc) and replace them with empty string. But I want to keep the smilies -:) or :( .I have written the following code but it is not working.

```
String s = ":,... :(..:::))How are you today?..:( ";  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\Q:)\\E|\\Q:(\\E)(\\p{P}+)");  
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);    
s = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Thank You.

Comment: How do you differentiate between punctuation that is part of the message and punctuation that is noise? (For example, the '?' in your example.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regex to match non-word characters BUT NOT smiley faces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465593/using-regex-to-match-non-word-characters-but-not-smiley-faces)

Comment: OOps I did a mistake in the question. The output should not have a '?' . Thanks . I just need to keep the emoticons like :) or :( and filter out other punctuations...

Comment: @pst (\\p{P}+) removes all the punctuations and (\\Q:)\\E|\\Q:(\\E) selects the smilies. Hence I am trying to select and replace the characters that are not the smilies and are punctuations..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[\p{P}&&[^:()]]|:(?![()])|(?<!:)[()]
```

A quick break down:

```
[\p{P}&&[^:()]]    # any punctuation mark except ':', '(' and ')'
|                  # OR
:(?![()])          # a ':' not followed by '(' or ')'
|                  # OR
(?<!:)[()]         # a '(' or ')' not preceded by ':'
```

Note that the `[ ... && [^ ... ]]` (set subtraction) is unique to Java's regex implementation. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

I tested in JavaScript with this:

```
[.,:;](?![)(])
```

So that would translate to something like one of these in Java

```
{Punct}(?![)(])
\\p{P}(?![)(])
```

Comment: That would leave the second `)` in `:))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
    String s = ":,...:(..:::))How are you today?..:( ";  
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(:\\)|:\\(|[^\\p{Punct}]+|\\s+)");  
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s); 
    String res="";
    while(matcher.find()){
        res+=matcher.group(0);
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

**Result**

> :( :) How are you today :(

Comment: Thank You!! Interesting approach!